# php + ssl project throws "This connection is not private" error

Tags: symfony, ssl, openssl

A few users of my web-application experience a "This connection is not private" error. Why is this happening and how can I best avoid this (since it is not a pleasant message, especially for new users)?

I am using symfony2 as my framework in combination with apache web server. 
Clicking on the green lock in the browser, the certificate says: GlobalSign Root CA -> AlphaRoot CA G2 -> *.my.domain.org

Comment: Can you provide more details ? (URL's / or is only local intranet ? )

Comment: No errors here. Also on Windows at the moment. Maybe this clients have a special security configuration in their Browser. All seems fine with the certificate.